# Rails serialization not dumping hash correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I have an active record model that has a column called `configuration` of type text. That column is serialized with a custom class, like so:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :configuration, MySerializer
end
```

The class `MySerializer` has the following class methods:

```
def dump(configuration)
  configuration.to_json if configuration
end

def load(configuration)
  obj = new
  obj.json_hash = JSON.parse(configuration) if configuration.present?
  obj
end
```

This instantiates an instance of the class `MySerializer` with the attr accessor `json_hash`.

Now, here's the problem, I'm doing:

`MyModel.create(configuration: {"key" => 1})`

And once I do `MyModel.first`, i get this:

```
...
configuration:
  #<MySerializer:0x00000007faa558
   @json_hash={"json_hash"=>{"key" => 1}
```

I was expecting getting something like:

```
@json_hash = {"key" => 1}
```

Any idea why I'd get the repeated key `json_hash` inside the attr accessor `@json_hash` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use MySerializer class?

Instead you can simply use as below:

```
serialize :configuration, Hash
```

Now do,

```
MyModel.create(configuration: {"key" => 1})
```

And try

```
MyModel.first
```